# Can any one explain me the structural difference between Proteins and Peptides?

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins

I have read in books that Proteins and Peptides are fundamental components of cells which carryout important biological functions.Can any one explain me the structural difference between Proteins and Peptides?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Have you tried to research this yourself? You should do this before posting — I am sure you will find an answer. If not, [edit] stating what you have found and why you are still unclear on the topic. See our [help on asking good questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Dear users of Biology Stack Exchange,I have been banned from asking new questions in Biology SE by the system.It's showing that "you have reached your question limit" and "sorry,we are no longer accepting questions from this account".That's why I'm editing my questions.Your up votes may help me in getting out of this ban.So,please upvote my questions if you like them.I didn't know about question ban previously till I had got imposed and no one told me about that ban.I would have improved my questions if I knew that.So,please help me in getting out of this ban with your upvotes to my questions.

Comment: Dear David and theforestecologist ◆,I'm unable to ask questions on Biology SE.Whenever i click on "Ask" option it's showing that "sorry,we are no longer accepting questions from this account" and it's telling that I need to edit my questions.I'm editing my questions for the second time after the question ban had imposed on me but the ban remaining as it is. Today i need to post a question and it's telling i should wait 6 months for posting that!! It's 'horrible' and facing this ban is 'too hard for me'.Please,can anyone help me in getting out of this ban? I will be thankful for that.

Comment: You need to ask about this on meta, if it will allow you. Then one of the mods will explain the situation to you. @theforestecologist is better placed than me as he is a moderator (the diamond indicates this) but you need the ampersand to alert anyone to a post. He should see the one I have included.

Comment: David and @theforestecologist ◆, i have already asked a moderator of Biology SE about this question ban nearly 25 days ago.He told me to improve the questions i have asked previously.I'm doing that and I'm also asking other people to help me in getting out of this question ban.

Comment: OK, the "homework questions..." is a close option that is often used when one thinks the question shows insufficient research. If you look at the [Help on asking questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), it says "search, and research". This question is really basic in relation to the definition of this site as being for "for biology researchers, academics, and students", so you would be expected to search on the internet on sites like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peptide) or [NCBI bookshelf](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21154/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In terms of structure*: both are composed of amino acids.

A **peptide** is when at least two amino acid are linked together.
A **protein** is composed of multiple amino acids and have a secondary, tertiary and even quaternary structure.

*In terms of function*: larger molecules have more complex functions.

**Peptides** can act as a intracellular or extracellular ligands which will activate a signal.

**Proteins** have a large array of functions (enzymatic, structural, receptors etc)

This article explains in more details the differences in proteins structure and functions:https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structural_Biochemistry/Proteins

Comment: pls include pictures :)